# Run tests in browser in angular app in run time

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I am building a angular app where i want to take user JavaScript code input(ex a function), run the unit test to verify if the input  code is proper and display to user if test has passed or failed. I run unit tests using angular CLI, but here i want to run tests during run time when user is using the application. It is similar to how freecodecamp runs unit tests to verify the user code input. I want to know how can i do this or is there any framework/library that supports it.

Comment: Test is just a function which has assertions (checks for values, calls etc.). You need to write your own functions that will run the code and then record the results

Comment: yes, but if there are libs like jasmine, chai etc available, then its better to use them especially for complex cases.

Comment: They are not meant for what you intend to do

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from runnung test in browser, you can use smth like https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular?file=src%2Fmain-testing.ts

1. So you create additional entry point for running tests.
2. Then in your main app you create textarea and allow to enter test as text.
3. Now create iframe that points to your new entry point and send there  your text, construct function and run it inside `it()`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in your unit tests is to actually instantiate the component and use web DOM objects and events with things like `document.getElementById` and such.

Or, you can use open source libraries that make it easier. One library you might look at is [testing-library/angular](https://testing-library.com/docs/angular-testing-library/intro/). While not as popular, my research concluded it's here to stay and its probably closest to what you're looking for.

Personally, I prefer [ng-mocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/). Proper use of it runs unit tests *so* much faster than normal angular *even though it mocks dependencies at run time* because it mocks entire modules, something programmers with deadlines don't... can't... bother to do... but you didn't ask about that. Specific to your question: [`ngNocks.click`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/ngMocks/click) or [`ngMock.input`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/ngMocks/input) make it easy. (Don't forget to call `fixture.detectChanges()` to trigger component re-rendering if your test requires it.)

The two really don't try to compete... testing-library is focused on what you're asking about, ng-mocks is focused on something else. However, my experience is that even though it feels like the UI helper functions in ng-mocks were thrown in as an afterthought,  they meet my needs so well that I never felt the need to look elsewhere.

Or, if you're looking for more than *unit* testing, you might want to look at web automation software like selenium for complete end-to-end testing.